# Cannot identify my graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade

After buying Company of Heroes 2 a few days ago I tried playing it for the first time and I ran into some serious fps problems. The screen I use for playing games is 1080p, but I couldn't get the fps above 30 unless I played it in a resolution of 720p and on lowest graphic settings. This isn't the first game where I had to do this, but it was the worst so far.

It got me thinking about upgrading my pc which would likely mean to upgrade my graphics card because it is pretty bad. These are my pc specs:

- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- Intel Core i5 processor 3470
- Nvidia Geforce GT 630 (2GB)
- 1 TB Hard Drive
- 6GB DDR3
- DVD-Super Multi drive
- Integrated LAN 10/100/1000

When I'm using my PC I run it with an extra 500GB external hard disk which is only used for backup, a TP-LINK wireless internet USB stick and a 4 port USB hub.

This is the power supply in my PC:

[image]

The next thing I did was look at the graphics card I was using which is [either one of these](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-630/specifications). or the OEM version. Which of the 4 is it?

This got me confused because except for the OEM version you need a minimum of 300W but my supply only seems to give 250W.

Did I read the power supply wrong, do I have the OEM version, is the data on the geforce website a bit too high or is there something else wrong?

Finally, can I upgrade my graphics card to something better without upgrading my power supply? Or should I really upgrade my power supply and get a better graphics card as well?

Comment: I cannot fathom that you could possibly run the system you described with a 250W PSU. I don’t think I’ve even seen an ATX 250W PSU; the last time I saw one that low, it was AT. I don’t see a date/year on the label, but the RoHS logo indicates that it’s from *at least* 2003. Frankly, I’m surprised that they even made 250W PSUs in 2003+. It looks like it’s a Chinese PSU which *might* explain it. I’d say that it’s not actually 250W but rather a mis-translation, however it looks like it really is 250W. What kind of [power](http://goo.gl/pY97yP) [connectors](http://goo.gl/gzzaCx) does it have?

Comment: I just entered the specified system in this [PSU calculator](http://support.asus.com/powersupply.aspx) (I didn’t enter any USB peripherals or anything not mentioned), and it came up with a recommended minimum of 350W.

Comment: A powerful but 77 Watt Max TPD CPU, a low power graphics card.. Not a gaming combo. I suspect it is a frankencomputer. Old one with upgrades.

Comment: I haven't build this pc myself, because I didn't want the extra work. Instead I got a standard Packard Bell one from a retailer.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

First, without enough power the system is likely to crash. It is very unlikely that it will perform slowly instead.

Secondly we come to:

> This got me confused because except for the OEM version you need a minimum of 300W 
>   but my supply only seems to give 250W

[The page you linked to](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-630/specifications) shows: Maximum **graphics card power** (W) 49 W / 65 W / 25 W

The most power hungry card in that page needs up to 65 Watt.

That does not mean that your system can run on 65 Watt. You need power to run all components (E.g. motherboard, RAM, drives, CPU, graphics, fans, ... ). Manufacturers take somewhat **average** values for a system, add some room to spare, round the number and then claim you need that much power.

It is **not** a hard requirement.

If you have a single SSD, a low power CPU etc then a 100 Watt PSU might do just fine.

If you have a dozen harddrives (each 10-15 Watt), a dozen fans, etc etc then you might need more power. The 250/300 Watt is just an estimate which will be safe for 99% of the poeple using that card.

> Did I read the power supply wrong, do I have the OEM version, is the data on the
>   geforce website a bit too high or is there something else wrong?

The power needed is always a tad high to be safe.

And this is probably a good thing since there are PSU's out there which fail before reaching their advertised maximum rating. FSP is a known brand though which made nice PSU. If they claim 16 AMP on the +12v rails then it probably can deliver that much. (and a graphics card usually uses a lot of power from the 12v rails).

> Finally, can I upgrade my graphics card to something better without upgrading my
>   power supply? Or should I really upgrade my power supply and get a better graphics
>   card as well?

I read this as "how much power can I use for my graphics card without upgrading my current PSU", and that falls down to three parts:

- Power available (not used by other components) for the graphics card.
- Power cables
- Cooling

For power available, either *guess* how much your system uses with one of the free calculators [like this one](http://www.extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp), or manually add some numbers:

E.g. [your CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/68316/) uses up to 77 Watt. A HDD will use 10-15 Watt when idle, or 25-ish Watt when it spins up. A fan will use 2-3 Watt. RAM will use 2-3 Watt. Etc etc. Then subtract that from what your PSU delivers and see if you have a safety margin left.

Second: The PSU you have probably did not come with 6 pins or 8 pins PCI-e connectors. You either need a PSU which does not need those (and that limits a PCI-e card to 75 Watt, which is the max it is allowed to draw via the PCI-e connector), or you will need a free molex connector and a molex-to-6pin_PCIe plug.

As for cooling: More power used -> more cooling needed. Rather obvious, but an old system in an old case might not be designed for that much heat.